# Как включить/выключить Wi-Fi программно?

Tags: android, wifi

Не могу решить проблему с включением/выключением Wi-Fi программно в Android.

Прописал permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Код, который использую для включения Wi-Fi:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

Ошибок в логах никаких нет, программа не вылетает, и при вызове `wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true)` ничего не происходит.

В чем может быть проблема?

Проверял как на своем телефоне, так и на эмуляторе — результат один и тот же.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не уточнили какая версия андроида на ваших тестовых устройствах. Вы используете такой метод:

```
public boolean WifiManager.setWifiEnabled (boolean enabled)
```

то что пишется про него в [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#setWifiEnabled(boolean)):

> This method was deprecated in API level 29. Starting with
> Build.VERSION_CODES#Q, applications are not allowed to enable/disable
> Wi-Fi. Compatibility Note: For applications targeting
> Build.VERSION_CODES.Q or above, this API will always return false and
> will have no effect. If apps are targeting an older SDK (
> Build.VERSION_CODES.P or below), they can continue to use this API.

как вариант сделать проверку на версию андроида:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
val panelIntent = Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY)
startActivityForResult(panelIntent, 0)
} else {
(this.context?.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as? WifiManager)?.apply { isWifiEnabled = true /*or false*/ }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

так как `startActivityForResult` тоже Deprecated, вместо него нужно использовать:

```
var resultLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                
            }
        }
```

итоговая версия для `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q`:

```
resultLauncher.launch(Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY))
```